# Expo's refreshing limitation

Tags: react-native, expo, pull-to-refresh

Good afternoon, I'm trying to make a push to update the request in my application by using expo's refreshing library but for some reason after a specific line of code refreshing won't work I have no idea why! I tried to make text fragments to see if it's a limitation on expo refreshing lib and it seems to be the problem, but is it really the limitation or am I taking something wrong here?

```
return (
    <View
      style={{
        height: "100%",
        width: "100%",
        //alignItems: "center",
      }}
    >
      <FlatList
        data={apidata}
        keyExtractor={(index) => index.toString()}
        scrollEnabled
        extraData={apidata}
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
          const image = { uri: "https://cryptoicons.org/api/white/btc/200" };
          return (
            <ScrollView
              refreshControl={
                <RefreshControl refreshing={refreshing} onRefresh={onRefresh} />
              }
            >
              <View
                style={{
                  alignSelf: "center",
                  marginVertical: 10,
                  width: "90%",
                  minHeight: 200,
                  flexDirection: "row",
                  marginLeft: "2%",
                }}
              >
                <LinearGradient
                  style={styles.collapsed}
                  colors={[
                    "(rgba(91, 118, 234, 0.053))",
                    "(rgba(41, 72, 170, 0.192))",
                  ]}
                >
                  <Text style={styles.SignalText}>{item.symbol}</Text>
                  <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", alignItems: "center" }}>
                    <View style={styles.statusBall} />
                    <Text style={styles.SignalText}>
                      Buy around : {item.enter}
                    </Text>
                  </View>
                  <View style={styles.cryptoLogo}>
                    <Image
                      style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
                      source={image}
                    />
                  </View>
                  <View>
                    <View
                      style={{ flexDirection: "row", alignItems: "center" }}
                    >
                      <Text style={styles.SignalText}>
                        Target 1 : {item.target_1}
                      </Text>
                      <View style={styles.statusBall} />
                    </View>
                    <View
                      style={{ flexDirection: "row", alignItems: "center" }}
                    >
                      <View style={styles.statusBall} />
                      <Text style={styles.SignalText}>
                        Target 2 : {item.target_2}
                      </Text>
                    </View>
                    <View
                      style={{ flexDirection: "row", alignItems: "center" }}
                    >
                      <View style={styles.statusBall} />
                      <Text style={styles.SignalText}>
                        Target 3 : {item.target_3}
                      </Text>
                    </View>
                    <View
                      style={{ flexDirection: "row", alignItems: "center" }}
                    >
                      <View style={styles.statusball2} />
                      <Text style={styles.SignalText}>
                        Stop loss : {item.stop_loss}
                      </Text>
                    </View>
                    <View
                      style={{ flexDirection: "row", alignItems: "center" }}
                    >
                      <View style={styles.statusBall3} />
                      <Text style={styles.SignalText}>
                        Leverage : {item.leverage}
                      </Text>
                    </View>              
                  </View>
                </LinearGradient>
              </View>
            </ScrollView>
          );
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
```

it will break on {item.stop_loss} no idea why

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to all the people who may be stuck at same issue the way that I fixed it was removing all the refreshing properties (in addition to RefreshControl) from `<ScrollView>` and adding them to refreshing & onRefresh Props in flat list

you can see these props [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#refreshing).

you still need to have the scrollview inside of the flatlist.

Hope this helps people who may stuck at this same as I did.